# Excel - Extracting substring after a character contained in a string

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract partial string contained within a cell after a certain character in the string.

I have a formula which can do this

```
=RIGHT(C10,LEN(C10)-SEARCH(":",C10))
```

But let's say the location of C10 cell isn't exactly known within the C column, and a way to locate it is by searching for a keyword in column D and then extracting the partial string using the above formula to a cell next to the keyword (column E).

I hope this makes sense.

Ex)

```
Column C
John: 1234 Alphabet Street 
Claire: 3456 Diamond Street
Tim: 333 Laugh Lane
Bo: 5555 Great Neck Street
Grace: 777 Whiteside Blvd

Column D
John:
Claire:
Bo:
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(D1&"*",C:C,1,0),D1,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott, your solution does the trick. However, it didn't work on my spread sheet because of an space I had before the string. So, for example instead of 
John: 1234 Alphabet Street
it's 
 John: 1234 Alphabet Street

This is because I had a formula to take out time stamp and user handle in the prior column.

Comment: (14:23:32) user-handle: John: 1234 Alphabet Street

Comment: So this leaves me with "(space)John: 1234 Alphabet Street". What would I need to adjust if the lookup were in B column (with timestamp and user handle)?

Comment: Change the `D1&"*"` to `" "&D1&"*"`

Comment: Disregard above comment. I figured out how to use TRIM and everything is good! Thank you, I learned something!

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work for you. First, modify the formula as below for the first row in E (i.e., E2)

```
=IF(ISTEXT(D2),RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(":",C2)),"No address found.")
```

In order to apply this formula throughout for the column triplets C, D and E do the following:  Click on the top-left corner of column 'C', hold and drag the cursor towards right to include columns D and E and now drag all the way down to the last row of C, D and E. Now, the formula is automatically applied to all the rows viz. C, D and E.

[image: Excel_substring_extraction_using_keyword 1]